# How to get pushed data out of child in userID child Firebase (Android)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with Firebase database. I want to get pushed user's data out of child in userID's(child). Please help me and explain how to get children out of unique user's child reference. I already can extract data out of userID child, but I can't move further. I was looking for almost everywhere and couldn't find answer.

Thanks in advance :)

[Here is the Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS9Vc.jpg)

**RULES**

```
{
/* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more 
about security rules. */
 "rules": {
 ".read": "auth != null",
 ".write": "auth != null"
 }
 }
```

**ViewDatabase**

```
package com.mcarrow.mapsservicerunning;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ViewDatabase extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG="ViewDatabase";
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private String userID;
private ListView mListView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_database_layout);
    mListView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    FirebaseUser user=mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    userID=user.getUid();
    mAuthListener=new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user =firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if(user!=null){
                Log.d(TAG,"Signed in"+user.getUid());
                toastMessage("Signed In"+user.getEmail());
            }else {
                Log.d(TAG,"Signed Out");
                toastMessage("Signed Out");
            }

        }
    };
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            showData(dataSnapshot);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            UserInformation uInfo = new UserInformation();
            ds= (DataSnapshot) ds.child(userID).getChildren();

uInfo.setName(ds.getValue(UserInformation.class).getName());
uInfo.setEmail(ds.getValue(UserInformation.class).getEmail());
uInfo.setPhone_num(ds.getValue(UserInformation.class).getPhone_num());
            Log.d(TAG, "showData: name: " + uInfo.getName());
            Log.d(TAG, "showzData: phone_num: " + uInfo.getPhone_num());
            Log.d(TAG, "showData: email: " + uInfo.getEmail());
            ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
            array.add(uInfo.getName());
            array.add(uInfo.getEmail());
            array.add(uInfo.getPhone_num());
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(mAuthListener!=null){
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
private void toastMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

**UserInformation**

```
package com.mcarrow.mapsservicerunning;

public class UserInformation {
private String Name;
private String Email;
private String Phone_num;
public UserInformation(){

}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    Email = email;
}

public String getPhone_num() {
    return Phone_num;
}

public void setPhone_num(String phone_num) {
    Phone_num = phone_num;
}
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.database.zza cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
    at com.mcarrow.mapsservicerunning.ViewDatabase.showData(ViewDatabase.java:73)
    at com.mcarrow.mapsservicerunning.ViewDatabase.access$100(ViewDatabase.java:23)
    at com.mcarrow.mapsservicerunning.ViewDatabase$2.onDataChange(ViewDatabase.java:58)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source:13)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source:71)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Probably you are casting `zza` to `SnapShot` which I'm not sure what database.zza stands for..

Comment: I tried to do it like that.

Comment: ds= (DataSnapshot) ds.child(userID).getChildren();

Comment: But it crashes..

Comment: Use something like this: `child("users").orderByKey().equalTo(mCurrent_user.getUid())` Also, the error seems coming from: `ds.getValue(UserInformation.class).getName()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in your database, you are using an extra child that I personally think is not needed. For the simplicity, I recommend you to use the following database structure:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- users
         |
         --- uid
              |
              --- Email: "egor@gmail.com"
              |
              --- Name: "Egor"
              |
              --- Phone_num: "24365675"
```

See, that extra level is missing now. To get the data of a single user, please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        UserInformation uInfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
        Log.d(TAG, uInfo.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

And if you want to get the data from all users, please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            UserInformation uInfo = ds.getValue(UserInformation.class);
            Log.d(TAG, uInfo.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Another problem in your code is that you are using in your model class fields that start with a capital letter and not with a lowercase letter. When you are using a getter named `getName()`, Firebase is looking for a field named **`name`** and not `Name`. See the lowercase `n` letter vs. capital letter `N`? So this will probably cause you problems. The correct way your model class should look like is this:

```
public class UserInformation {
    private String name, email, phoneNum;

    public UserInformation() {}

    public UserInformation(String name, String email, String phoneNum) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getEmail() { return email; }
    public String getPhoneNum() { return phoneNum; }
}
```

Delete your old data, add fresh data and everything will work fine.